# Downloading an old app released for an older version of iOS

Tags: ios-appstore

I am trying to download the [YACHT & JET DESIGN app](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/yacht-jet-design/id594389299?mt=8) on an iOS device running iOS 11. I am unable to do so. The app was released during iOS 7.

How do I download it?

Comment: As it says on top of the screen in the App Store: "The developer needs to update the app to make it work with iOS 11" (paraphrasing from german). So even if you are able to download it, it will just not work.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I do not believe it is possible. You may have to find yourself an iOS device that already has iOS 7 on it in order to download this app.

It is also likely that even if you could download it, it just would not run as iOS has changed a **lot** since iOS 7.

If you have an iOS device that supports iOS 7 you may be able to jailbreak it and install an earlier version of iOS (iOS 7) from unauthorized download locations. But that is way beyond the scope of what we discuss and support here. So you would have to go elsewhere for help with that.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from the App Store screenshot, the app has not been updated to work with iOS 11. Hence, you will not be able to download/install this app on your iPad running iOS 11.

[image]

You may still be able to install it on an iPad running iOS 7 - iOS 10, if you have access to one such device.

Technically speaking, iOS 11 lacks support for running 32-bit apps. The reason this app cannot be installed is because the developer of this app is yet to add support for 64-bit.

You may wish to get in touch with the developer by visiting their web-site mentioned in the App Store page to check if and when they are planning an update.